# Why synchronization doesn't work whereas I have 265 MB of free space

Tags: sync, storage

Snchronization doesn't work whereas I have 265 MB of free space:

[image]

Why?

I use Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.